# Trust relationship between workstation with PBA/Encryption and domain failed

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, disk-encryption

I have installed some endpoint encryption solution on a laptop and from that point I could not login into the workstation with another user. Windows always tells me that the trust relationship between workstation and domain failed. I installed and initilaized it all by the user, let's name him A. I wanted to make user B to be able to login at the PBA. Therefor I had to login to the PBA with user A and login with user B on Windows.

In this case the encryption solution would see that and automatically update the PBA in order to make it possible that user B is able to login to the PBA. But all I get when trying to login with user B on Windows is the relation ship problem.

Interesting: Trying user A at the PBA and on windows is possible. Is windows lying? Why does the trust relationship problems occur when another person is able to use the computers account within the domain?

Comment: What is a PBA??

Comment: Pre-Boot Authentication